# React-Leaflet GeoJSON Tooltip Appears in Two Places - How to Fix?

Tags: geojson, react-leaflet

I'm working with React-Leaflet and have encountered an issue with tooltips in a GeoJSON layer. I've used the onEachFeature function to add a tooltip to each feature using bindTooltip with `sticky: true`. The tooltip behavior is as expected on mouseover, appearing over the mouse pointer. However, when I click on a feature, the tooltip also appears in the middle of the GeoJSON feature, which is not desired.

Here's a brief outline of my code: https://codepen.io/qiun/pen/bGZpzYm

I've tried various approaches to resolve this, including adding specific coordinates to the tooltip, but nothing seems to work.

I've prepared a demo available at CodePen, with the problematic behavior and some screenshots for mouse evenets [mouseover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjx1Z.jpg) and [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIheM.jpg) for clarity

Could someone help me understand why the tooltip is appearing in the center of the GeoJSON feature on click and suggest a way to prevent this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those who will be looking for a solution. You need to use the L.popup({}) object to which I manually attached mouseover and mouseout interactions.

```
function GeoJSONComponent({ data }) {
  const onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
      const popupContent = feature.properties.name;

      layer.on("mouseover", function (e) {
        this.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup(e.latlng);
      });

      layer.on("mousemove", function (e) {
        this.getPopup().setLatLng(e.latlng);
      });

      layer.on("mouseout", function () {
        this.closePopup();
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <GeoJSON
      data={data}
      onEachFeature={onEachFeature}
      style={() => ({
        color: data.properties.color,
        weight: 3
      })}
    />
  );
}
```

This removes the problem of the "tooltip" element appearing in two places.

Working example: https://codepen.io/qiun/pen/wvOWQKN